# Joomla hiding "article" <h1> title

Tags: php, html, joomla

I am working on Joomla, I have a little problem... When I click on a link in the main menu which is an article, the heading title of the section became the word "Article". Any idea on how to fix this problem?

Comment: Please provide some code, preferably the minimal amount to reproduce the problem, it's impossible for us to hazard a guess otherwise.

Comment: Show us some screen-snap showing what you mean ? Also mention the Joomla version you are working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joomla has this built in. Since you didn't post your version, it's hard to be sure, but it's probably going to be in the global article options (Content > Article Manager > Options) or in the menu settings (Menus > your_menu > your_menu_item > Article Options).

You shouldn't need to modify template files or write CSS. That's a last resort and can make undoing those changes more difficult later.

Comment: Hello I'm sorry I can't provide you a screenshot right now. I had already tried your solution but it doesn't seem to work. To avoid the problem I made an invisible menu, but I would like to try a different solution as my client will have to insert new articles himself. Btw tnx

Comment: I see you've accepted the answer. Did you get it working? Menu item settings override article settings, so maybe that's an issue for you.